# send a part of request.path to url_for Python/HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

my url is `http://example.com/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl`
Now I have a-tag like this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('category',
                    feature=request.path+"+"+att.get('u_sg'))}}">
                    {{ att.get('name') }}
                </a>
```

request.path is giving me '`/en/cat/ap+da+wh_pl`' BUT, I need only `/ap+da+w_pl`
How to do it?

I need to pass only 'ap+da+w_pl' from out of request.path from HTML only, as I have to use it in pre-coded View of Flask and my view is like THIS:

```
@app.route('<lan_c>/cat/<string:feature>')
def category(feature, page):
```

- Consider current url is 'http://example.com/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl'
  if user click on a-tag then I want to append value returned from 'att.get('u_sg')'.
- The problem I am facing right now is my a-tag is considering 'http://example.com/**en/cat/en/cat**/ap+da+w_pl+w_pl2', so I wanted to send only 'ap+da+w_pl' + 'att.get('u_sg')'. So that a-tag will point to 'http://example.com/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl+w_pl2'

Comment: just add ur <string:feature> to render_template parameter dictionary? and then use it in jinjia?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the result by `/` and get the last key:

```
>>> r = 'http://example.com/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl'.split('/')
>>> r[-1]
'ap+da+w_pl'
```

This would work for `/en/cat/ap+da+wh_pl` the same way:

```
>>> r = '/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl'.split('/')
>>> r[-1]
'ap+da+w_pl'
```

Prepend the `/` if needed:

```
>>> '/'+(r[-1])
'/ap+da+w_pl'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to pass only 'ap+da+w_pl' from out of request.path from HTML only, as I have to use it in pre-coded view of Flask and my view is like THIS: @app.route('<lan_c>/cat/<string:feature>')
def category(feature, page):

Comment: Add that to your question, or any other missing `defs`, etc. It's unclear which part of request.path is what also, so you might consider adding a breakdown of each variable.

Comment: Isn't `feature` the part you need? I'm not sure why you couldn't just use that.

Comment: feature is request.path+"+"+att.get('u_sg'), which is  "/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl" (where request.path = /en/cat/ap+da and att.get('u_sg') = w_pl) Now I need only need "/ap+da+w_pl". I dont need "/en/cat/" (which is '<lan_c>/cat/') from category view

Comment: Are you wanting to do this from your `def category`? If so then you could just apply the same idea from my answer there. (eg. directly underneath the `def category(feature, page):` Using something like `str = '/'+feature.split('/')[-1]` should give you the part you want.

Comment: No, I won't be able to do it from there as it will not reach the def category at all because URL is invalid "'http://example.com/en/cat/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl+w_pl2"( valid URL "http://example.com/en/cat/ap+da+w_pl+w_pl2")